# How do I get the co-ordinates by passing the variables

Tags: javascript, reactjs, lodash

I am trying to get the cartesian neighbour . So I am trying to get the following output,

```
function getOutPut(x, y){

  

}
```

output would be:

```
for x: [[1,1],[1,2],[1,3],[2,1],[2,3],[3,1],[3,2],[3,3]]
for y : [[-18,6],[-18,7],[-18,8],[-17,6],[-17,8],[-16,6],[-16,7],[-16,8]]
```

what I tried is. :

```js
const neighbours = [
  [-1, -1],
  [-1, 0],
  [-1, 1],
  [0, -1],
  [0, 1],
  [1, -1],
  [1, 0],
  [1, 1]
];

function getOutPut(x, y) {

  const results = neighbours.map(([dx, dy]) => ({
    x: x + dx,
    y: y + dy
  }));
  console.log("results is", results)
}

getOutPut(2, -17)
```

This is what I am gettting. So , How do I fix this ?

Comment: could you explain more about your expected output?

Comment: More info necessary on output and input relationship ?